# In how many ways can $n$ people be arranged in a row if two specified people are neither of them to be at either extremity of the row?

Tags: combinatorics

My interpretation of the question: $n$ people are to be placed in a row, with two specific individuals not allowed to be at the beginning nor the end of this row (they can interchange with each other however).

Permutations of the two specific individuals and their two positions: $^nC_2\cdot2!$

Permutations for the rest of the men and their places: $(n-2)!$

Multiply the two and get: $^nC_2\cdot2!\cdot(n-2)!=n(n-1)(n-2)!$

But the answer is given as $(n-2)(n-3)(n-2)!$

So something is wrong with my calculation of the two specific individuals. But I don't see it. It makes sense for me that two people in two positions have this permutation: $^nC_2\cdot2!$

Comment: Your calculation allows for the specific individuals to be placed anywhere in the row.

Comment: Why $^nC_2\cdot2!$? Don't you want $^{n-2}C_n\cdot2!$?

Comment: I'd do it this way. Put somebody at the left end, $n-2$ choices. Then put somebody at the right end, $n-3$ choices. Then arrange the remeining $n-2$ people between the ends, $(n-2)!$ ways.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the solution. Why is someone at the left end $n-2$ and someone at the right end $n-3$? And what does $n-2, n-3$ mean anyway? My thinking is if someone is at the left end, then the remaining people will be $n-1$, and the permutations for the remaining spots will be $(n-1)!$. The person at the left end has only one possibility: occupying that one spot. Same goes for the right end.

Comment: I start by picking somebody to go to the left end. There are $n$ people, but two of them are unavailable for the end positions, so I have $n-2$ people to choose from. I choose one of those $n-2$ people to go to the left end. There are $n-2$ ways for me to choose which person to send to the left end. After that, I choose somebody to go to the right end. Of the original $n$ people, two are unavailable for end duty, and one has already been assigned to the left end. That leaves me with $n-3$ people who are available for the right end. I choose one of those people.

Comment: After I've filled the two end positions, I'm left with $n-2$ unassigned people. I assign those $n-2$ people to the $n-2$ positions between the ends. There are $(n-2)!$ ways to do that.

Comment: Wow that's an amazing explanation bof. Thanks! I can't believe how it's so simple yet I can't understand it. Something's wrong with my intellect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $8$, $n$, people ...

One end: $6$ choices,  $(n - 2)$
The other end: $5$ choices, $(n - 3)$
The remaining 6 positions: $6!$, $(n - 2)$

Total number of permutations: $6 \times 5 \times 6! = (n - 2)(n - 3)(n - 2)!$

*Cogito* ...